# Is it necessary to put css, js and images in static folder in django

Tags: javascript, css, django, linux, python-3.x

I am new to Django and Python Programming. I am confused, why it is necessary to put css, javascript and images in static directory in django.

Can we put these files in templates like other html files and link them directly in the html code

for eg:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="myscript.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<img src="mypic.jpg">
</body>
</html>
```

Where both index.html, myscript.js, style.css and mypic.jpg lie in same directory i.e. templates in Django.

Comment: Why would you put them in the templates directory? They're not templates. What would be serving them from there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When projects of different magnitudes are carried out, we will always have css, javascript, images, among others, it is advisable to separate each of these elements in their respective folders.

And django suggest use one folder: **static** within this exist other folders such as :

- js
- css
- images.. etc..

and your pages(html) is on the **templates folder**, now for use static folder and all your content you maybe need setup on:

**settings.py**

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
    '/static/',
]
```

Add this code for say to django that use static...

The **base.html** is a suggest , for example if I prefer use bootstrap or materialize or other framework css is prefer implement on this(base.html), for futures changes only you change on one file ...

**example base.html**

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.min.css' %}">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    {% block body%}

    {% endblock %} 

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="{% static 'jquery/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'popper/popper.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

i use **{% load staticfiles %}** for load the static content , the url use **"{% static 'url/to/file/css/or/js/or/image' %}"**

on this case i use bootstrap i'm going to implement on **login.html** this pages is on template folder.

**code on login.html:**

```
{% load staticfiles %}

{% include "base.html" %}
{% block body %}
<!--HERE IS MY CODE FOR CREATE A LOGIN -->
  <form>.....your code for login...or do you need..!!</form>
{% endblock%}
```

i include the base.html with **{% include "base.html" %}**
good luck..
[this is a tutorial Django](https://tutorial.djangogirls.org/en/)
and for write my code is between the tag **block** and **endblock**

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using a Python/Django backend, you have to link the static, "front-end," files separately. This becomes particularly useful when connecting to a database (AWS/S3, for example) and for 'collectstatic' when you deploy your app. If you don't have a top-level static folder, and you try to run `python3 manage.py collectstatic` in your terminal, it won't run correctly and any styling that you've done won't be deployed properly.

Within the static folder, there should also be a separate 'css', 'js', and 'images' folder. For the JavaScript file, it really depends on what you're using it for and if you're planning on needing parts of it rendered on HTML pages that extend to your base HTML (child templates).

You would need the following:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="{% static 'js/myscript.js' %}"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}">
</head>
<body>
<img src="{% static 'images/mypic.jpg' %}">
</body>
</html>
```

You'll also need to add `{% load static from staticfiles %}` at the top before `!<DOCTYPE html>` on your base HTML page as well. If you want your CSS/JS/Images to show up on any HTML that you're extending from your base HTML (child templates), make sure to add

`{% extends 'yourbasepage.html' %}`
`{% load static from staticfiles %}`

in any child HTML pages.

For the image, this code applies only if you're not getting it from a model and rendering it into the HTML template with a for loop.